# Subnet problems with a new Wifi Access Point

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router

I have a standard router Wifi device.   I have added second WiFi Access point which plugs into the router using Cat5/RJ45.

The router works on 192.168.1.x, however the New access point works on 192.168.10.x

Now anything I connect to the new access point can access the internet, but it can no longer access anything on my 1.x network (such as printers and other computers).

What is the best way around this?

I can control the subnet of the WiFi Access point, but what settings should I be putting in for the gateway and so on.

Thanks

Comment: Don't let the AP do DHCP, make the main router the only source

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to configure the AP onto the same network as the original router; as well as doing this you'll want to turn off any services the AP is providing which the router already provides such as DHCP, dns, etc.